# The SDK directory is not writable but flutter wanted to install Android SDK in the directory

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-doctor

I try to run my testprogram. The android studio replies "The SDK directory is not writable (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk)".

Well flutter doctor wanted me to install it in this directory to make flutter find the SDK. What can I do to fix it?